# Run async/await function call from class as one-liner

Tags: javascript, async-await

I am having a class with a function that is using a promise (for simplicity I am using `console.log()`):

```
class Foo {

    constructor() { }

    async func(s) {
        try {
            await console.log(s)
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e.message);
        }
    }
}

module.exports = { Foo };
```

When I call the function in my `main.js` file I want to wait until the promise finished and then execute the next step:

```
const {
    Foo
} = require('./t22_1-async-await-class')

let foo = new Foo()

foo.func("1. Before Promise").then(() => {
    console.log("2. Promise")
})


console.log("3. Later...");
```

However, I get:

```
1. Before Promise
3. Later...
2. Promise
```

I would like to execute the `func()` and only then run the next `console.log()`.

I know that I could use a `.then()` and wrap the `console.log("3. Later...");` in it. This gets very confusing if I have a lot of code that I would like to execute after that.

Is there anther way to execute `func()` without using a `then()`?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: this is how promise work. async/await don't change it

Comment: `Is there anther way to execute func() without using a then()?` no

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use top level await (not real one since it's still [WD](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-top-level-await))

---

```
async function main(){
    const {
        Foo
    } = require('./t22_1-async-await-class')
    let foo = new Foo()

    await foo.func("1. Before Promise")
    console.log("2. Promise")
    console.log("3. Later...");
}
```